# Why is there difference in output for list(path) vs path in Depth First Search in line 12?

Tags: python, python-3.x, recursion, data-structures, graph

This is a code for DFS all paths from source to the destination where source = 0 and destination = size of the graph - 1. In Line 12, why can't I simply do `res.append((path))` since the path is already a list?

```
from collections import defaultdict
class Solution:
    def allPathsSourceTarget(self, graph: List[List[int]]) -> List[List[int]]:
        adjlist = defaultdict(list)
        for i in range(len(graph)):
            adjlist[i].extend(graph[i])
        start = 0
        destination = len(graph) -  1
        res = []
        def dfs(node,path):
            nonlocal res
            if node == destination:
                res.append(list(path))
                return 
            if node in adjlist:
                for nextNode in adjlist[node]:
                    path.append(nextNode)
                    dfs(nextNode,path)
                    path.pop()
        dfs(0,[0])
        print(res)
```

Comment: If you `return res`, this passes [leetcode](https://leetcode.com/problems/all-paths-from-source-to-target). `list(path)`  makes a shallow copy of the `path` object, otherwise you're just appending an alias of the same list over and over again and winding up with corrupt results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you simply pass the path, it passes a reference to the path variable.
Essentially, you would be referring to the original path variable.

`list(path)` would essentially append a shallow copy of the path as a new list, hence changes made to the path will not be reflected.